# c# operator overloads, do i need to deep copy?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, deep-copy

I have an Ascii class to help me manage and string with char limits, and i want to be able to increment it like a char, so I have some operator overloads. Given the following code:

```
 public static AsciiWord operator++(AsciiWord aWord){
        aWord.numValue++;
        return aWord.Copy();
    }
```

Do I really need the copy?

Note: Copy is a extension method I copied off of SO that performs a deep copy of just about anything.

Comment: It's probably better to implement a method with appropriate name instead of overloading `operator ++`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The increment operator is supposed to leave the original value unchanged, and return an incremented copy of it. However, in your implementation, you're mutating the `aWord` passed in as an argument.

E.g., the following code uses the post-fix increment operator and expects `oldValue.NumValue` to be 0, but with your current implementation it will be 1.

```
AsciiWord aWord = new AsciiWord { NumValue = 0 };
AsciiWord oldValue = aWord++;
Assert.Equal(0, oldValue.NumValue); // fails

int i = 0;
int oldIntValue = i++;
Assert.Equal(0, oldIntValue); //passes
```

In other words - `AsciiWord` should be deeply immutable.

Comment: So then are you suggesting I deep copy first, then ++ the copies numValue, then return copy?

Comment: That would be somewhat acceptable, but the ideal solution would be to make `AsciiWord` completely immutable. That is, make sure every field is marked as `readonly` and, *every single time* you need to change one of its fields/properties, you'll be forced to create a whole new objects. Like `string`.

Comment: And that goes for both `AsciiWord` and all types it depends on. If you can't do that, I'd suggest going with Henrik's suggestion - implement an `Increment()` method instead of overloading the `++` operator.